# Running a Dockerhub Image in Ubuntu 18.04 with MongoDB image and Nginx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

So I have a Nodejs app with a Github action pipeline to a private Dockerhub repo which creates an image once a push is made to `main` branch using below `Dockerfile` within the app directory

```
FROM node:12.21.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "konet.js" ]
```

I have pulled the image into my Ubuntu 18.04 server running Nginx and also pulled `mongo` image from the official Dockerhub Mongo image.

I can run both the `mongo` image and my private docker image (`docker-username/docker-image`) independently and adding the `--net` flag, I'm able to connect to mongodb from the app container.

My Challenge:

1. Is it possible to create an Nginx proxy to route to the app container port 4000?
2. What is the right way to run a `docker-composer.yml` file that can take care of these processes instead of running the images individually?

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` on the server:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    nodeserver:
        build:
            context: ./app
        ports:
            - "4000:4000"
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:latest"
        container_name: my_mongo
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
```

But I keep getting this error:
`build path /home/devUser/app either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build error indicates you don't have the `app` directory next to the compose file. Since you already have a ci process to build the image I'd suggest using the built image by specifying `image: docker-username/docker-image` as the image for the nodeserver service in your compose file. You will need to log in with an account that can access the private image on your server (just run `docker login` and put in your credentials).

This is how your compose file would look like with the image specified instead of building it:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    nodeserver:
        image: docker-username/docker-image
        ports:
            - "4000:4000"
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:latest"
        container_name: my_mongo
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
```

Now, to your other questions:

You can absolutely use nginx to proxy requests to your app. To do this, you need an nginx configuration similar to this one:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodeserver:4000;
    }
}
```

This will forward all requests made to the nginx container to the `nodeserver` service on port `4000`.

You then need to mount the config in your nginx container, something like this instead of building it:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    nodeserver:
        image: docker-username/docker-image
        ports:
            - "4000:4000"
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:latest"
        container_name: my_mongo
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
```

By default, all services in a docker compose file can automatically see each other over the network by their name as if they were separate machines in a "classic" private network.
Because of that you won't need to expose any ports from the containers which don't need to be reachable from the outside world which are all containers except the nginx container. I would strongly recommend to follow this advice unless you know what you're doing. Especially exposing things like the mongo db can get very dangerous very quickly once some scanner stumbles upon that open mongo server on the internet. A cleaned up `docker-compose.yml` would look something like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    nodeserver:
        image: docker-username/docker-image
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:latest"
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
```

I would suggest you to look into [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) which makes this very easy and can do a lot more like auto tls, multiple domains, access restrictions etc.

Comment: Thanks @kolaente trying with your approach, the app container cannot connect to MongoDb `connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xx.x.x:27017` then Nginx also `failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream http://xxx.xx.x.x:4000/`

Comment: What did you configure for the mongodb connection in your app?

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db_name`

Comment: That needs to be `mongodb://mongo:27017/my_db_name`. `mongo` is the name of the mongodb service in your compose file and since all of the services in your compose file are in the same network, the other services (=your node app) can talk to the mongodb service with that name.

Comment: Tanks a lot. That worked just perfectly as expected. Just one clarification in case someone has same issue, the values for `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml` should have a preceding `./` to avoid `Named volume "mongodb:/data/db:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.` error.